# SimpleDB SDB machine hours - How to check?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

So I know the AWS console removed simpleDB a little ago to promote DynamoDB, but how do you track how many "machine hours" you have consumed so far?

Ive read AWS documentation pretty thoroughly and several forums posts but most people just address the issue that machine hours are hard to estimate, but doesnt mention HOW to actually monitor the current usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope of your query? Are you trying to investigate a single instance that you already have running? Or are you trying to figure out the science behind the cost process?

This is a breakdown of the process: [enter link description here](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-25-dissecting-simpledb-boxusage.html).  You can use "cost explorer" to evaluate your existing spend for an instance you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SimpleDB calculates the total machine utilization (in hours) called "Box Usages". Box-Usage returned by Amazon SimpleDB in the response. Amazon SimpleDB simply calculates the total machine utilization (in hours) and multiplies it with machine utilization rate ($/hour) to figure out your transaction costs.

http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/pricing/